# Why do I get "ń" instead of "ñ" when typing Alt code?

Tags: windows-7, unicode, character-encoding, alt-code

I'm learning Spanish and I just type the Alt code of `ñ` character. It should be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0241</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>241</kbd>, but when I type that I get a `ń`.

I'm using a Windows 7, Hungarian version.

It is really annoying. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your [question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to include what research you've done on your own in attempt to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alt-codes do not depend on the font, they depend on your system's locale.

Alt-codes that do not start with zero use your console codepage. Alt-codes that start with a zero use your ANSI codepage. The alt-codes are in decimal

In US English locale, the console codepage is CP-437 and the ANSI codepage is Windows-1252. The letter `ñ` is available in CP-437 at 164 and at 241 in Windows-1252. That's why the alt-codes that people suggested to you work.

But you are using Hungarian locale, so your ANSI encoding is Windows-1250, and your console encoding is different too (I'm not sure which one it is). They both do not have `ñ`. Windows-1250 has `ń` at 241.

There are several ways you can solve your problem:

- install the Spanish keyboard layout and switch when needed;
- switch your entire system to some Western European locale (not recommended);
- enable hexadecimal Unicode Alt-codes: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows);
- install [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) and create your own custom keyboard layout, with `ñ` and any other characters you want.

I had a similar problem and I picked the last solution.

Comment: In the given context (a Hungarian learning Spanish), I’d use the last solution too: use MSKLC to modify a Hungarian keyboard so that <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> produces ñ (and similarly implement Ñ, ¿, and ¡).

Comment: I made my own keyboards as well.  It's not hard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

With a hungarian keyboard you can type most of the frequently used spanish letters except the "eñe". I've already installed spanish keyboard but if I change the input method it also changes the "í" "á" "ú" etc. So I think I'ts easeier and faster to just assing a key to "eñe". 

 I've installed Microsoft Keyboard Layout creator. It works like charm. Thank you very much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alt + 164? Try a different font.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. Doesn't work. 

I don't know if it's depending on the font. No matter sofware I use (browser, word processor, etc.) always the same result :-/